# Complexity of a combinatorial constraint

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, computability-theory

For two $k$-partitions $X,Y\in k^\omega$ of $\omega$
(seen as functions $\omega\rightarrow k$),
we say $X,Y$ are *almost disjoint*
iff $X^{-1}(i)\cap Y^{-1}(i)$ is finite
for all $i<k$.

Question: Does there exist a   set 
$Q\subseteq 3^\omega\times (2^\omega)^r$
such that:

1. for every $X\in 3^\omega$, there exists $Y\in (2^\omega)^r$  such
   that $(X,Y)\in Q$;
2. for every $(X^0,Y^0),(X^1,Y^1)\in Q$, if    $X^0,X^1$ are almost
   disjoint,  then $ Y^0_s,Y^1_s$ are almost    disjoint for some $s<r$.

If $r=1$, then obviously  $Q$ does not exist since every three $2$-partitions, there are two of them not almost disjoint and there are three $3$-partitions that are mutually almost disjoint. If we replace $3^\omega$ by $2^\omega$ then such $Q$ obviously exist. It seems, by Cohen forcing,  $Q$ (if exist) cannot be $\Sigma_1^1$. Could it be $\Pi_1^1$?

Comment: In 2, did you mean for some $s < r$, rather than all $s < r$?  Because as it is now, making $r$ larger makes it harder for such a $Q$ to exist, and so your argument for $r=1$ settles the question.

Comment: It is "for some $s<r$". Thanks~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes for $r=3$. Take an ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ on $\omega$. Define a function $f \colon 3^\omega \rightarrow 3$ such that $f(X):=i$ iff $X^{-1}(i) \in \mathcal{U}$. Note that if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are almost disjoint, then $f(X_1) \neq f(X_2)$.

Let $Q:=\{(X,Y) \in 3^\omega \times (2^\omega)^3 \colon \,\, f(X)=i \Rightarrow Y_i=(\emptyset,\omega) \land f(X)\neq i \Rightarrow Y_i=(\omega, \emptyset)\}$.

Unfortunately, this $Q$ cannot be $\Pi_1^1$ as Jonathan pointed out.

Comment: For $r=4$, it seems that you can get $Q$ to be $\Pi^1_1$. Let $\mathcal{U}$ be a $\Sigma^1_2$ ultrafilter (say in L). Then we take exactly the same $Q$ as you did, but simply add an additional coordinate to the $Y$ part for the witness that $f(X)=i$.

Comment: The $Q$ that you define will never be $\Pi^1_1$, since $x \in \mathcal{U}$ would become $\Pi^1_1$, but this is impossible for an ultrafilter.

Comment: Concerning your second comment, I had the same idea, just wasn't 100% sure that an ultrafilter cannot be $\Pi_1^1$.... How does this relate to your $\Pi_1^1$ P-point base (in L)? Can't I just say $X \in \mathcal{U}$ iff $\forall Y \in \mathcal{B} \colon X \cap Y \neq \emptyset$?

Comment: Concerning your first comment, I assume you mean taking a witness from a $\Pi_1^1$ ultrafilterbase in L? However, this $Q$ might not work in $V$ as condition (1) need not be absolute?!

Comment: The formula $\forall Y \in \mathcal{B}(X \cap Y \neq \emptyset)$ is $\Pi^1_2$ since you need to say $\forall Y (Y  \notin \mathcal{B} \vee X \cap Y \neq \emptyset)$.

Comment: My first comment was just a consistency result. In $L$ it is not hard to construct a $\Sigma^1_2$ ultrafilter. A $\Sigma^1_2$ set is the projection of a $\Pi^1_1$ set $A \subseteq 2^\omega \times 2^\omega$, so if $x \in \mathcal{U}$, then there is a witness $y$ so that $(x,y) \in A$.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right!! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for answering~ I didn't expect different $r$ would make a difference. Your construction gives a $Q$ for $r=2$ as following. Put $(X,Y)$ in $Q$ where $Y=(\emptyset,\emptyset), (\emptyset,\omega), (\omega,\emptyset)\in (2^\omega)^2$  depending on $f(X)=0,1,2$ respectively. Where $(\emptyset,\emptyset)$ denotes such $(Y_0,Y_1)\in (2^\omega)^2$ that $Y_0^{-1}(1)=Y_1^{-1}(1)=\emptyset$ (similarly for $(\emptyset,\omega), (\omega,\emptyset)$). So $Q$ could be $\Pi_1^1$ for $r=3$ by Jonathan's comment.